# Bing Maps V8 not working with IE, Chrome, and Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, bing-maps

I am trying to upgrade Bing maps from V7 to V8. But when I changed the map script URL to reference V8, the map sometimes shows with Internet Explorer browser and not working at all with Chrome and Firefox browsers

here is the code that I am using to load Bing map

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'></script>
        <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'></script>-->
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <div id="divMapView" style="width:800px;height:500px"></div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMapView'), {
                credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key'
            });
        </script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

What else should I do to get my code working with all browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got two solutions for this issue one for synchronous and another for asynchronous loads

**1- For synchronous load: Load The map on "onload" page event**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <head> 
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol'></script>
        <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'></script>-->
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <div id="divMapView" style="width:800px;height:500px"></div>

         <script type="text/javascript">
             var loadMap = function () {
                 var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMapView'), {
                     credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key'
                 });
             }

             window.onload = loadMap;
        </script>

    </body> 
</html>
```

**2- For asynchronous load: It will work normally without issues**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
        <!--<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0'></script>-->
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="divMapView" style="width:800px;height:500px"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                    function GetMap() {
                        var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMapView'), {
                            credentials: 'My Bing Maps Key'
                        });
                    }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's ridiculous that either of these approaches is required. Your original code *should* have been supported out of the box.